# python sqlite3 блокировка базы

Tags: python, aiogram, sqlite3

Всем доброго времени.
Пишу бота на aiogram,делаю наполнение базы sqlite3 с сайта по ключам пользователей api/есть 3 функции которые парсят данные и наполняют базу.

Читал, что запись должна происходить 1 процессом, а чтение допускается несколькими.

В боте делал через scheduler вызов функций по таймеру, происходило пересечение функций, как я понимал одна еще наполняла база, и запускалась другая, так же делал чтение из базы на наличие новых сообщений для отправки пользователю-в результате чего прилетал блок базы.

вывел функции по наполнению базы в отдельный файл и начал запускать cronom.
но периодически ловлю блокировку базы.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/apscheduler/executors/base_py3.py", line 30, in run_coroutine_job
    retval = await job.func(*job.args, **job.kwargs)
  File "/home/main.py", line 86, in foto_message
    for i in users_id_api():
  File "/home/db.py", line 91, in users_id_api
    info=cur.execute("SELECT id,api,api_feedback FROM users WHERE action=1 ").fetchall()
sqlite3.OperationalError: database is locked
```

что я делаю не так, или sqlite3 вообще не предназначена для такой работы, только для статический данных..??

заранее благодарю.

Comment: Поймав ошибку блокировки, просто ждём некоторое время и повторяем операцию. / Если есть возможность, следует использовать одно и то же соединение во всех потоках, тогда доступ к БД будет автоматически сериализован.

Answer (score 0):

> Эта ошибка возникает, когда несколько процессов используют один и тот же файл сеанса, то есть при запуске двух или более клиентов, при этом используя то же имя сеанса или в случае, если к файлу обращалась другая программа.

https://docs.pyrogram.org/faq/sqlite3-operationalerror-database-is-locked

Comment: Или же, короче, кто то использует вашу базу данных, поэтому вы не можете получить к ней доступ

Comment: Здравствуйте, примерно понял , но как быть, а если 1000 пользователей попросят данные из БД?
начитался про кэширование или смены движка БД Postgress или аналоги.

подскажите.что значит разные имена сеансов?

Comment: Имя сеанса под которым находится подключение базы данных. Так то, на aiogram код один, и если 1000 пользователей попросят данные из БД то все будет нормально. Но если вы откроете программу 2 раза, то ничего не получится. Эта ошибка возникает когда какая то другая программа использует эту базу данных

Comment: как мне быть, мне нужно наполнять базу -обновлять данные, и так же делать запросы к ней- это как раз 100 пользователей

Comment: могу вам в телеграм написать?

Comment: Все что вы выше написали, происходит через один скрипт aiogram скрипт ( наполнять базу -обновлять данные, и так же делать запросы к ней), соответственно, все будет нормально (так как скрипт один). А если несколько скриптов будут подключаться к базе, то будет ошибка. Телеграм @nicknamer091